# Install Smiley font for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I Need to use my own smiley icons (like emoji) in my textfield and all around the project. Is there any way to install the fonts in iOS. Please suggest me for the right way...

I got that there is no solution for the installation. I created manual keyboard using scrollview and buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be easy, as long as you know which glyphe is which smiley:

Have a look at [Custom Fonts in iOS 4](http://blog.beefyapps.com/2010/06/custom-fonts-in-ios-4/) at beefyapps.com.

**EDIT**

The Emoji Icons are a stored in the private use area of unicode. They won't look any good on a different device than an iPhone/iPad, this is Apple specific.

The app is just to enable the keyboard. You can do it yourself: [Making An Emoji Enabeling App](http://blog.beefyapps.com/2010/06/custom-fonts-in-ios-4/).

Have a look at [The truth about iPhone Emoji](http://inner.geek.nz/archives/2009/02/06/the-truth-about-iphone-emoji/), which sheds some light on the whole topic.

Comment: But I need to show the keyboard for the custom font. Because I need to use the smileys... Do u hav any idea about that. Is there any way to show the custom keyboard by installing font on IOS.... :)

Comment: No the keyboard will always show a font defined by apple. If you need a smiley keyboard you'll have to write it yourself.

Comment: You can't, not as far as I know. You can do it easily with a UIWebView.

Comment: But there are apps that enable the emoji keyboard - they do do it somehow.

Comment: the emoji keyboard is an international keyboard. The glyphs are stored in the private use area of unicode, this is absolutely apple specific. Send a text message with a beer glass to someone with an android handy and she will receive at most a cryptic symbol.

Comment: For the record, Unicode 6.0, released in October 2010, added hundreds of emoji characters. I’m not sure if fonts in iOS already have glyphs for emojis; on Mac OS 10.6.7, stock fonts don’t support them yet.